# Debian user keeps getting killed

Tags: debian, user, debian-squeeze, su

I keep getting booted out of one of the user account on my Debian Squeeze server.  At first I thought that it had something to do with SSH, but it still happens even if I log into another account and then `su` to the problem account. The first account does not get disconnected.

For example:

```
good_user@hostname:~$ su problem_user
Password:
problem_user@hostname:/home/good_user$ Killed
good_user@hostname:~$
```

If I wait about a minute, it always prints *Killed* and then logs me out. It also kills all of my processes and screen sessions. It does not matter if I run commands or not. I couldn’t find anything in the logs related to this problem.

Any ideas what the problem could be or how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

If it prints "killed" you received a SIGKILL.

what could cause this is a `killall -9 -u youruser` that is somewhere in a cronjob or something...

check crontab -l and /etc/cron.d/*

What user is this? A service user or something?

Comment: I just created a user to run an application in the background.  It is a fresh install of Debian.  There is nothing related to killing the user in the cron tab.